# download large csv file after manual processing of queryset

Tags: django

I have a model in Django:

```
class MyModel(models.model):
    a = models.FloatField()
    b = models.FloatField()
```

It contains > 10.000 items.

In my view I need to get all the items, do something with each one of them, and return csv file with a result:

```
def myview():
   allitems = MyModel.objects.all()
   for i in allitems:
       i.a = random.random()
       i.b = random.random()
       i.save()
       # WRITE_TO_CSV HERE
       return HttpResponse(allitems)
```

The problem is that since I have manually process each item in `allitems` query, it takes a long time. What is the correct way to redirect a user to a resulting page to download file when it is ready without bumping into timeout issue?

Comment: what really do you need may be `update` can help you?

Comment: It sounds like you need to create the file in the background, that is not possible with plain Django. You would need to implement an asynchronous task queue like Celery. https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/20/how-to-use-celery-with-django.html